# Issues with datatables, yadcf, select2 and closeOnSelect (select multiple entries at once)

Tags: datatables, jquery-select2, yadcf

I am using datatables width yadcf and select2 with the multi_select option.

I want to passtrough the option `closeOnSelect: false` to select2. The result doesn´t work like expected: Only the first selected value gets filtered. The other entries are only highlighted.

The goal is to select multiple entries at once like in the third select box.

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u5xp36gz/1/

Comment: looks like a bug in integration with select2, you can open an issue on yadcf

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue opened regarding this in yadcf git repo mentioned below:
[Using "closeOnSelect:false" with select2 only work for the first element](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/594)

According to their comment, the problem is due to the `select2 version`. They checked with the version `select2 version (3.5.4)` and its working fine.

In my case I have checked with the `select2 version 3.5.4`, the `closeOnSelect:false` is working fine, though there are some design issue.

Here how I used the option:

```
    yadcf.init(myTable, [
                    {column_number : 0,
                        select_type: 'select2',
                        filter_container_id: "id_of_inputField",
                        filter_type: "multi_select",
                        filter_match_mode: "exact",
                        select_type_options: {
                            width: '100%',
                            closeOnSelect : false,
                        }}
])
```